# Execute action when all threads in except main are finished? (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading

I use wxpython for GUI. In main thread I fired some threads in background and showed modal dialog in main thread immediately. Now I want this modal dialog to be updated with some info at the moment all background threads finish they job. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Pass a Queue as an argument to the threads, and let them put() a done / result object into that. Then count them.